# How to make struct with this json?

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, struct

How to make a struct model with this JSON? I've watched many tutorials on youtube but I'm still confused, and what's the meaning of using enum on struct?

```
{
  "err_code": 0,
  "data": {
    "message": "Success",
    "result": {
      "check_in": [
        {
          "created_at": "2022-06-20 10:00:37",
          "late": "True",
          "location": "Jl. H. Asmawi No.63, Beji, Kecamatan Beji, Kota Depok, Jawa Barat 16421, Indonesia",
          "place": "GRIT OFFICE",
          "folder": "./pegawai/grit/2022/06/20/masuk/10/00/",
          "filename": "0000_rakha_fatih_athallah_picture.jpg",
          "tujuan": "",
          "link": "http://103.140.90.10:8081/face-recognition/client/python/pegawai/grit/2022/06/20/masuk/10/00/0000_rakha_fatih_athallah_picture.jpg"
        },
        {
          "created_at": "2022-06-16 11:23:12",
          "late": "True",
          "location": "Jl. H. Asmawi No.63, Beji, Kecamatan Beji, Kota Depok, Jawa Barat 16421, Indonesia",
          "place": "GRIT OFFICE",
          "folder": "./pegawai/grit/2022/06/16/masuk/11/23/",
          "filename": "0000_rakha_fatih_athallah_picture.jpg",
          "tujuan": "",
          "link": "http://103.140.90.10:8081/face-recognition/client/python/pegawai/grit/2022/06/16/masuk/11/23/0000_rakha_fatih_athallah_picture.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "check_out": []
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my struct model. This is important because I want to use jsondecoder with this struct. I want using jsondecoder later.

```
import Foundation

struct jsonData : Codable{
    var err_code : Int
    var data : Data
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case err_code = "err_code"
            case data = "data"
        }
}

struct Data: Codable{
    var message : String
    var result  : Result
}

struct Result : Codable {
    var check_in  : [Checkin] = []
}

struct Checkin : Codable{
    var created_at : String
    var late : String
    var location : String
    var place : String
    var folder : String
    var tujuan : String
    var link : String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case created_at = "created_at"
            case late = "late"
            case location = "location"
            case place = "place"
            case folder = "folder"
            case tujuan = "tujuan"
            case link = "link"
        }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://app.quicktype.io/?l=swift. Side note: Never name a custom struct `Data`❗️. It could interfere with `Foundation.Data`

Comment: so thats why i always keep getting error Foundation.Data, i don't know i should change the name or not before because the json key name is data so I thought I should make the variable name match the json key so i need to change the name with codingkey?

Comment: No you need to change the name of the struct

Comment: Be aware that the names of the structs are not related at all to the JSON **keys**. Actually they represent the **values**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the structs you have are very close to what is required, just minor tweaks such as:

```
struct Response: Codable{
    var err_code: Int
    var data: DataObj
}

struct DataObj: Codable{
    var message: String
    var result: Result
}

struct Result: Codable {
    var check_in: [Checkin]
}

struct Checkin: Codable, Hashable {
    var created_at: String
    var late: String
    var location: String
    var place: String
    var folder: String
    var tujuan: String
    var link: String
}
```

Use it like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var apiResponse: Response?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let response = apiResponse {
                Text("message: \(response.data.message) ")
                Text("check_in.count: \(response.data.result.check_in.count) ")
            List {
                ForEach(response.data.result.check_in, id: \.self) { chk in
                    Text("created_at: \(chk.created_at) ")
                }
            }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            let jsonStr = """
                 {
                 "err_code": 0,
                 "data": {
                 "message": "Success",
                 "result": {
                 "check_in": [
                 {
                 "created_at": "2022-06-20 10:00:37",
                 "late": "True",
                 "location": "Jl. H. Asmawi No.63, Beji, Kecamatan Beji, Kota Depok, Jawa Barat 16421, Indonesia",
                 "place": "GRIT OFFICE",
                 "folder": "./pegawai/grit/2022/06/20/masuk/10/00/",
                 "filename": "0000_rakha_fatih_athallah_picture.jpg",
                 "tujuan": "",
                 "link": "http://103.140.90.10:8081/face-recognition/client/python/pegawai/grit/2022/06/20/masuk/10/00/0000_rakha_fatih_athallah_picture.jpg"
                 },
                 {
                 "created_at": "2022-06-16 11:23:12",
                 "late": "True",
                 "location": "Jl. H. Asmawi No.63, Beji, Kecamatan Beji, Kota Depok, Jawa Barat 16421, Indonesia",
                 "place": "GRIT OFFICE",
                 "folder": "./pegawai/grit/2022/06/16/masuk/11/23/",
                 "filename": "0000_rakha_fatih_athallah_picture.jpg",
                 "tujuan": "",
                 "link": "http://103.140.90.10:8081/face-recognition/client/python/pegawai/grit/2022/06/16/masuk/11/23/0000_rakha_fatih_athallah_picture.jpg"
                 }
                 ],
                 "check_out": []
                 }
                 }
                 }
                 """
            // simulated response data
            let data = jsonStr.data(using: .utf8)!
            do {
                self.apiResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
                print("\n---> apiResponse \(apiResponse)")
            }
            catch {
                print(" error \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: big thanks man thats worked, i also have another question here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72694998/how-to-loop-this-in-the-view-according-to-the-amount-of-created-at-data-present

Comment: finally i get the response after post request

Comment: I have a question about how can I showing it on my view like showing it according to how much data i have

Comment: glad I could help. If my answer helped you, could you mark it as accepted please. Regarding your other post/question, well you know what to do now, use the `Response` model.

Comment: sure! fell free to check my other question:)

Comment: thanks, updated my answer with some display of info.

Answer (score 1):

We use `CodingKeys` in order to use custom names for the ones in the `JSON`.

For example, you have `created_at` but you don't want the underscore, what you would do is name your variable `createdAt` and in the `enum` add `case createdAt = "created_at"`

As for the decoding part, it's actually pretty easy:

```
do {
    //let data = the json data you got.
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let model = try decoder.decode(jsonData.self, from: data)
}catch {
    print(String(describing: error))
}
```

Please note that we don't use lowercase letters when naming `structs, classes, actors & enums`.

Edit: Thanks to [Marek R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1387438/marek-r) for pointing out that sometimes the names in the `JSON` can match keywords specific to the used language (i.e: `Swift`), so it is necessary to implement `CodingKeys`.

Comment: I'd like to point out that some times it happens that name in JSon sometimes matches keywords from language used. So possibility to use different names in code and in JSon is necessity sometimes.

Comment: Ohhh so thats how  codingkeys work i think i get it now, thanks for the explanation

Comment: and by the way, is the struct that I created is correct according to the json?

Comment: For snake case you can use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/keydecodingstrategy/convertfromsnakecase